# I chose to UDP as my peer 2 peer service, and how can I prove it's reliable in my situation

Tags: java, linux, udp, debian

I have two debian servers located on the same subnet. They are connected by a switch. I am aware the UDP is unreliable.

> Question 1: I assume the link layer is ethernet. And MTU from a standard
>   Ethernet is 1500 bytes. However, when I did a ping from one server to
>   another, I found out that the maximum packet size can be sent is
>   65507. Shouldn't it be 1500 bytes? Can I say, because there's no router in between these two servers, therefore, the IP datagram will
>   not be fragmented.
>
> Question 2: Because two servers are directly connected with a switch, can I
>   assume that all datagrams arrives in order and no loss on the path?
>
> Question 3: How can I determine that the chances of datagram dropped
>   at the server because of buffer overflow. What size to set the receive buffer so that datagram will not overflow receive buffer.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Perhaps you should check out http://serverfault.com/

Comment: You can't 'prove it's reliable in [your] situation', because it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  UDP is not even reliable between processes on the same machine.  If packets are sent to a socket without giving the receiver process time to read them, the buffer will overflow and packets will be lost.

1. You did your ping test with fragmentation enabled.  Besides that, ping doesn't use UDP, but ICMP, so the results mean nothing.  UDP packets smaller than the MTU will not be fragmented, but the MTU depends on more factors, such as IP options and VLAN headers, so it may not be greater than 1500.
2. No.  Switches perform buffering, and it's possible for the internal buffers to overflow.  Consider a 24 port switch where 23 nodes are all transmitting as fast as possible to the last node.  Clearly the connection to the last node cannot handle the aggregate traffic of 23 other links, the switch will try to buffer packets but eventually end up dropping them.

   Besides that, electrical noise can corrupt packets in transit, causing them to be discarded when the checksum fails.
3. To analyze the chance of buffer overflow, you could employ queuing theory to find the probability that a packet arrives when the buffer is full.  You'll need some assumptions regarding the probability distribution on the rate of packet transmission and the processing time.  The number of packets in the buffer then form a finite chain, hopefully Markov, which you can solve for the steady-state probabilities of each state in the chain.  Good search keywords to find out more would be "queuing theory", "Markov chain", "call capacity", "circuit capacity", "load factor".

---

EDIT: You changed the title of the question.  The answer to your new question is: "You can't prove something that isn't true."  If you want to make a reliable application using UDP, you should add your own acknowledgement and loss handling logic.

Comment: Could you give me some reference by saying "UDP is not even reliable between processes on the same machine." And if I set the receiver a multiplier of the sender buffer, can I say the chances of end side buffer overflow is minimum.

Comment: @KevinQ (a) UDP is unreliable period. You don't need a reference saying it is unreliable in a specific stuation. (b) No.

Answer (score 0):

The 64 KB maximum packet size is the absolute limit of the protocol, as opposed to the 1500 byte MTU you may have configured (the MTU can be changed easily, the 64 KB limit cannot).

In practice you will probably never see reordered datagrams in your scenario.  And you'll probably only lose them if the receiving side is not processing them fast enough (or is shut off completely).

The "chances" of a datagram being dropped by the receiver is not something we can really quantify without knowing a whole lot more about your situation.  If the receiver processes datagrams faster than the sender sends them, you're fine, otherwise you may lose some--know how many and exactly when is a considerably finer point.

Comment: 64 KB is 64 kilobytes > 1500 byte. And where do you get the 64 KB from?

Comment: @Kevin: From IPv4, which has a fragment offset field that maxes out at 64k.

Comment: @BenVoigt The maximum size of an IPv4 datagram is 65535-28=65507 bytes.

Comment: @EJP: Are you sure?  The last fragment should be able to get all the way to 64k (theoretically it could even go beyond, but I believe the spec forbids that).

Comment: @BenVoigt You're forgetting about the IP header (20 bytes) and the UDP header (8 bytes).

Comment: @EJP: No, I'm not.  Each fragment can only have a payload of size (MTU - IP header), but the total IP payload of all fragments combined can be a full 64k.  Then the total UDP payload can be (64k - UDP header)

Comment: @BenVoigt you can't just have fragments in the void. You have to start with an actual IP packet and you have to end up with one as well. That packet has to have an IP header and you have to subtract that from the space available for the payload.

Comment: @EJP: Oh, so your argument is based on the size after reassembly?  I guess I can believe that.

Comment: @BenVoigt The size before fragmentation and after reassembly. There has to be an IP packet to fragment in the first place, and you can't construct one whose size > 65535, ergo you can't construct a UDP datagram with payload > 65509.

Answer (score 0):

1. The IP stack will fragment and defragment the packet for you. You can test this by setting the  the no-fragment flag. The packet will be dropped.
2. No. They will most likely come in order, and probably not dropped, but the network stack, in your sender, router and receiver, are free to drop the packet if it can't handle it when it arrives. Also remember that when a large packet is fragmented, one lost fragment means that the whole packet will be dropped by the stack.
3. I guess you can probe by sending 1000 packets and measure loss, but historical values does not predict the future...

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:  You are confusing the MTU with the tcp maximum packet size see [here](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/networkprotocols/g/mtu-maximum.htm)

Question 2: Two servers connected via a switch does not guarantee datagrams arriving in order.  There will be other network transmissions occurring that will interfere with the udp stream potentially causing out of sequence frames

Question 3: Answered by Ben Voigt above.

Comment: TCP has nothing to do with it.